# Defining a Distribution by using Integral of partial derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Show that $\langle f,g \rangle:=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\partial g (t,t^2) }{\partial x} dt$
for $g(x,y) \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$

defines a Distribution $f \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$

As far as I know I need to show linearity and continuity.

But before I start I am a little bit confused by the expression.

What does $g(t,t^2)$ mean?
Do I just handle $t$ and $t^2$ like two seperate variables?
And if so since $g$ depends only on $t$ and $t^2$ all partial derivatives with respect to $x$ are equal zero. This sounds very wrong to me.

Is there some typo? And If so could someone write down the correct expression (or give me a link or something).

If it's not a typo, it would be nice if someone could tell what I am understanding wrong.

---

**Edit:**

Now my calculations/thoughts
Showing convergence:
Let $g_n$ be a testfunction which converges to $g$

Since $D^\alpha g_n \rightrightarrows D^\alpha g$ for $\alpha  \in \mathbb{N}^2$

One can interpret $\frac{\partial g_n (t,t^2) }{\partial x}$ being dependent on two variables $t$ and $t^2$
Because $D^\alpha g_n \rightrightarrows D^\alpha g$ for $\alpha  \in \mathbb{N}^2$, this implies that $\frac{\partial^m g_n (t,t^2) }{\partial x^m}$ $\rightrightarrows$ $\frac{\partial^m g (t,t^2) }{\partial x^m}$.

Considering now that $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\partial g_n (t,t^2) }{\partial x} dt= \frac{\partial g_n (t,t^2) }{\partial x}$

The only thing left to show is
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\partial g_n (t,t^2) }{\partial x} dt \rightrightarrows \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\partial g (t,t^2) }{\partial x}$.
This holds because $g_n$ is uniformly convergent, thus we can interchange the limits.

Would be very thankful if someone could tell me, if my calculations are correct? (If not I would probably need some held)

Comment: I believe it can be interpreted as "partial derivative of $g$ with respect to $x$, evaluated at the points $t,t^2$"

Comment: The integrand is $\partial_x g(x,y) |_{(x,y)=(t,t^2)},$ i.e. first take the derivative of $g(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and then set $x=t$ and $y=t^2$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "defines a Distribution $f \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$" (that you have missed an apostrophe)?

Comment: @md2perpe yes you are right. I edited it

Comment: In case of continuity I need a sequence $g_n$ and show that with $g_n \rightarrow  g \Rightarrow <f,g_n> \rightarrow <f,g>$ Did I understand it correct?

Comment: That's correct. Remember that the convergence $g_n \to g$ should be in the space $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^2).$

Comment: BTW, use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>` to get better looking brackets: $\langle f, g \rangle$ instead of $< f, g >.$

Comment: @md2perpe thanks for both hints.

Comment: Your are defining the distribution $f$, evaluated on a test function $g$, in terms of an integral along the parabola $\{(t,t^2):t\in\mathbb R\}$ of the derivative of $g$ in its first argument...

Comment: @md2perpe I did an edit to the question showing my calculations. Could you tell me if they are correct? (I hope I am not bothering you)

Comment: @John.W. I think that it lacks some reasoning. For example, how do you know that the integral is not infinite?

Comment: @md2perpe If I remember correctly $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^1 \cap L^2$, and since $g_n \in  \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ this should ensure that the Integral is finite.

Comment: @John.W. But you integrate along a path $(x,y)=(t,t^2)$ that might make things change. Consider the spiral $(x,y)=(\frac1t \cos t, \frac1t \sin t)$ winding around origin, and a test function $g$ supported on a neighborhood of origin. Then $h(t):=g(\frac1t \cos t, \frac1t \sin t)$ would not have compact support anymore. Instead, $h(t) \to g(0)$ as $t\to+\infty.$